# Excel - checkbox equivalent that will work on Android tablet

Tags: android, excel

Short version: in excel, how can I replicate the functionality of a simple checkbox (no VBA, just simple link to a cell value) so that it will work on an Android tablet?

Context:

My small business has an excel spreadsheet that is used for their employee timesheets. It has served them well for years because most of their employees were labourer type employees, and they filled out a printed copy and put them in the accounts filing tray each week.

In recent years, we have more and more office-based, PC-using employees, and employees working at remote sites, so we tweaked the spreadsheet to support electronic completion and submission. Part of this process included adding checkboxes in cells where the employees used to physically tick a cell, to confirm that their lunch break was taken (or not) on a given day. The checkboxes don't do any VBA, they just link to a cell (which becomes TRUE/FALSE), and that TRUE/FALSE value is then used in a formula to determine whether or not to deduct 0.5 hours for lunch when calculating the total hours.

Now we have a few employees who use Android tablets, and the checkbox doesn't work. All the checkboxes display a yellow warning triangle, and if you click on them you get the message "This version of Excel doesn't support running or interacting with form controls".

Is there another feature I could use to (preferably) make the same form work correctly across both PC and Android, or (alternatively) create an Android-friendly version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using data validation with an in-cell dropdown to force the user to select "yes" or "no". I then tweaked all my formulas so that instead of directly using the TRUE/FALSE boolean, they use an IF(A1="Yes") expression for the boolean condition.

A little messy, and not the one-click solution I was hoping for, but at least the data validation dropdowns are supported by excel mobile.